Is it possible to design a random partition with good concentration performance?
Assume that I have n points that I wish to partition into two groups A, B. My requirement is that for each point $x_i$, the marginal distribution $P(w_i=\mathbb{1}\{x_i \in A\})=e_i$, for some pre-specified $e_i$, and I also want that the concentration to be "good", i.e., $\sum_{i=1}^n 1- \frac{w_i}{e_i}=C$ with high probability. Note that this concentration is not true if we allow each $x_i$ to be independently randomly assigned with probability $e_i$.
When $e_i=e$, there is a direct partition method, which is uniformly randomly use a subset of $ne$ $x_i'$s. In this case, $\sum_{i=1}^n 1- \frac{w_i}{e_i}=0$. But when $e_i$ is different, is there anything I can do with it? I appreciate any idea or related techniques.
